# Insert hidden digest in pdf using iText library

Tags: java, security, pdf, itext, digest

I search a method for insert a digest (byte array or String) into PDF file using iText library (Java). I create the digest from a String with this method:

```
private String crypt(double x, ByteArrayOutputStream baos) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException{
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    md.update(String.valueOf(x).getBytes("UTF-8"));
    md.update(String.valueOf(baos).getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] digest = md.digest();

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(byte d:digest){
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & d));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The digest should be not seen in PDF, but it must be exctracted for comparison.

Comment: `String.valueOf(baos).getBytes("UTF-8")` --- are you sure you do not actuially want `baos.toByteArray()`? Furthermore, concerning the original question, by *he digest should be not seen in PDF* you mean that it should not be displayed as part of the content? Thus being accessible for PDF processing software is ok?

Comment: Thanks for the help, for the first part you have right I changed now; for the second part yes the digest should not be displayed in the content but, yes, should be accessible in software processing

Answer (score 5):

Such private data can be stored in **PieceInfo** dictionaries:

> *A page-piece dictionary (PDF 1.3) may be used to hold private conforming product data. The data may be associated with a page or form XObject by means of the optional **PieceInfo** entry in the page object (see Table 30) or form dictionary (see Table 95). Beginning with PDF 1.4, private data may also be associated with the PDF document by means of the **PieceInfo** entry in the document catalogue (see Table 28).*
>
> *(section 14.5 of [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

In your case the **PieceInfo** in the document catalogue seem most apropos.

Using iText you can store data there and retrieve them back again like this using the `DocumentPieceInfo` helper class below:

### Storing document **PieceInfo** data

```
PdfName appName = new PdfName("MYAPP");
PdfName dataName = new PdfName("Hash");

DocumentPieceInfo dpi = new DocumentPieceInfo();

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(...);
dpi.addPieceInfo(reader, appName, dataName, new PdfString(data));

PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ...);
stamper.close();
```

### Retrieving document **PieceInfo** data

```
PdfName appName = new PdfName("MYAPP");
PdfName dataName = new PdfName("Hash");

DocumentPieceInfo dpi = new DocumentPieceInfo();

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("target/test-outputs/test-with-piece-info.pdf");
PdfObject myData = dpi.getPieceInfo(reader, appName, dataName);
```

### The `DocumentPieceInfo` helper class

```
public class DocumentPieceInfo
{
    static PdfName PIECE_INFO = new PdfName("PieceInfo");
    static PdfName LAST_MODIFIED = new PdfName("LastModified");
    static PdfName PRIVATE = new PdfName("Private");

    void addPieceInfo(PdfReader reader, PdfName app, PdfName name, PdfObject value)
    {
        PdfDictionary catalog = reader.getCatalog();
        PdfDictionary pieceInfo = catalog.getAsDict(PIECE_INFO);
        if (pieceInfo == null)
        {
            pieceInfo = new PdfDictionary();
            catalog.put(PIECE_INFO, pieceInfo);
        }

        PdfDictionary appData = pieceInfo.getAsDict(app);
        if (appData == null)
        {
            appData = new PdfDictionary();
            pieceInfo.put(app, appData);
        }

        PdfDictionary privateData = appData.getAsDict(PRIVATE);
        if (privateData == null)
        {
            privateData = new PdfDictionary();
            appData.put(PRIVATE, privateData);
        }

        appData.put(LAST_MODIFIED, new PdfDate());
        privateData.put(name, value);
    }

    PdfObject getPieceInfo(PdfReader reader, PdfName app, PdfName name)
    {
        PdfDictionary catalog = reader.getCatalog();

        PdfDictionary pieceInfo = catalog.getAsDict(PIECE_INFO);
        if (pieceInfo == null)
            return null;

        PdfDictionary appData = pieceInfo.getAsDict(app);
        if (appData == null)
            return null;

        PdfDictionary privateData = appData.getAsDict(PRIVATE);
        if (privateData == null)
            return null;

        return privateData.get(name);
    }
}
```

This class assumes the **Private** value to be a dictionary in which in turn the private data are stored. It may be anything, though. To process the private data generated by other programs, you may need some variation.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will prove it soon :)

Comment: I proved it and i prove to change more thing, but not save the dictionary into pdf file... and i have no idea which save this dictionary in pdf...

Comment: Have you done what is described in the section "Storing document PieceInfo data"

Comment: The data I store in the dictionary isn't saving when I open the pdf up again and try to find what I stored. How do I save?

Comment: @Luminous *"The data I store in the dictionary isn't saving when I open the pdf up again and try to find what I stored. How do I save?"* - See section "Storing document PieceInfo data" of the answer

Comment: Wow! Thanks for coming back to this. I had `var fs = new FileStream(...); var reader = new PdfReader(fs); dpi.addPieceInfo(...); var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs); stamper.close();` Need to use a SEPARATE FILESTREAM INSTANCE. `var reader = new PdfReader(new FileStream(...)); dpi.addPieceInfo(...); var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(...)); stamper.close();` The "Storing document PieceInfo data" could be a bit clearer on that.

Comment: Indeed, you must use different streams. As that is true in general when working with iText,, I didn't mention it again in this specific context.