# Store large hidden text/string to a PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: string, pdf, out-of-memory, itext

I want to store a large string in PDF document somewhere hidden. Right now I have a hidden text field in which I am writing that text. The problem is that when the string size increased upto **10MB** I start getting `OutOfMemory` errors.

What will be the best way to store some large hidden string/text to PDF document using `iTextSharp`? That text/string should be retrieved later as well.

Comment: *hidden* - hidden from whom? Should it merely not be displayed in a PDF viewer? Or should someone inspecting the PDF more seriously also not find (or, considering the amount of data, not be able to read) your data?

Comment: Hidden from whoever opens the PDF, no one should know that something extra is with the PDF. It will be good if it is secured, right now it is in a hidden text field with text field name known to us only (not much secured).

Comment: You might want to look at [this answer to "Insert hidden digest in pdf using iText library"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462211/insert-hidden-digest-in-pdf-using-itext-library/18465343#18465343). You obviously should encrypt the information using a cipher of your choice. And as you talk about data 10 MB and up, you may want to use PDF streams instead of strings.

Comment: @mkl That link helped. I am still testing it but it's working.

Comment: @mkl I can able to work with it but the generated PDF size is too much which is more than 10MB now. You can add this comment as an answer if you want, I will accept it. Now I have tried the attachment way to do the same task and I have the following question http://stackoverflow.com/q/22627011/867475

Comment: Adding 10MB of data to a PDF will make the PDF larger by 10MB. Is your target to add 10 MB in *such* an invisible way that it even will not show in the file size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such private data can be stored in **PieceInfo** dictionaries, also cf. [David's answer to the OP's follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22628386/1729265).

[This answer to the older question "Insert hidden digest in pdf using iText library"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18465343/1729265) shows how to make use of **PieceInfo** dictionaries in general using iText/Java (differences to iTextSharp/C# should be minimal here).

As the OP talks about data 10 MB and up, he may want to use PDF streams instead of strings.

The `DocumentPieceInfo` helper class provided in that older answer can be used with PDF streams for BIG DATA like this (again in Java as I'm mostly living on the Java side, and again porting to C# should be easy):

### Storing document **PieceInfo** data

```
PdfName appName = new PdfName("MYAPP");
PdfName dataName = new PdfName("BigData");

DocumentPieceInfo dpi = new DocumentPieceInfo();

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(...);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ...);

InputStream in = ... BIG DATA INPUT STREAM ...;
PdfStream stream = new PdfStream(in, stamper.getWriter());
stream.flateCompress();
PdfIndirectObject ref = stamper.getWriter().addToBody(stream);
stream.writeLength();
in.close();

dpi.addPieceInfo(reader, appName, dataName, ref.getIndirectReference());

stamper.close();
```

### Retrieving document **PieceInfo** data

```
PdfName appName = new PdfName("MYAPP");
PdfName dataName = new PdfName("BigData");

DocumentPieceInfo dpi = new DocumentPieceInfo();

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("target/test-outputs/test-with-piece-info.pdf");

PdfObject myDataObject = dpi.getPieceInfo(reader, appName, dataName);
myDataObject = PdfReader.getPdfObject(myDataObject);
byte[] myData = PdfReader.getStreamBytes((PRStream)myDataObject)
```

Comment: Thanks @mkl, that seems to be perfect. I was trying to do this since your first comment but always getting some reference errors, now it is  working. I also understand Java code better :)