# How to add a secure and hidden attachment to a PDF document using iTextSharp

Tags: security, pdf, itext, attachment

I want to attach a file to an existing PDF document using `iTextSharp` and I can able to do it using `pdfStamper.AddFileAttachment(...)` method. Now I want to make the attachment hidden/secure in a way that no one able to see the attachment and even not able to retrieve it directly from PDF. It should only be retrieved from code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't store anything that has to be hidden in a File Attachment. That's a public, well-known mechanism that is understood and supported by multiple pieces of software (through UI).

If it has to be hidden and secure, I would protect the file by encrypting it in some way and then store all of it in a private CosStream somewhere in the document. The best way to do this would likely be the "Page-Piece Dictionaries" which provide a way to store product private data inside a PDF file. Private data can be attached to forms, pages or the document as a whole.

In my version of the PDF specification, this is paragraph 14.5, Page-Piece Dictionaries.

To include the concern of the OP and mkl's subsequent comment, there is no set expectation that Page-Piece data is encoded in any set way. The Page-Piece Dictionary contains a "Private" key that can have anything as value (so the value can be a string for smaller data, could be a dictionary containing multiple pieces of private information, or could be a stream that is compressed to keep it small).

From the PDF specification: "Private (key) : (Optional) Any private data appropriate to the conforming product, typically in the form of a dictionary". Remark the "typically" in the description. Further explanation in the PDF specification clarifies that the type of data stored may be anything you want.

Comment: I am currently using Page-Piece Dictionaries to do this task, but the final file size is now a concern for me. The string that I am storing in PDF can have size more than 10MB. So the initial PDF size from 500KB is moved to around 12-13 MB which is too much. After using attachment the PDF size moves upto 800KB with a compressed file. Due to this huge difference I was thinking if there is any way  to secure the attachments.

Comment: @rizzz86 As I mentioned in the comment (in which I pointed towards **PieceInfo**): *as you talk about data 10 MB and up, you may want to use PDF streams instead of strings.* **PieceInfo** entries are not required to be strings, streams are also possible and streams can easily be (and in iText by default are) compressed.

Comment: Absolutely correct, I've edited my answer to include that information.

Comment: @rizzz86 I added iText sample code for storing and retrieving streams referenced from document **PieceInfo** dictionaries as [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22632201/1729265) to your former question [Store large hidden text/string to a PDF using iTextSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22602200/1729265).

Comment: Thanks guys. Anyone can find the complete code here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22632201/867475 by @mkl